# Opening a backbone view in a new window

Tags: backbone.js, javascript, trigger.io

i am developing a trigger.io application using backbone, the entire app is in one page but i need to open a detail page in a new window (not a modal view, a tab in android).

I don't know if it's possible to render a view in a new window, or write to history the view and navigate to the url.

Can anybody give me some tips.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open a special view, specify a route calling this view.

Now you create a simple link with target blank to the route.

The application gets started in the new window and loads the action mapped to the route.

I think this is the best solution to do this, although there are ways to create windows and communicate between them in JavaScript. If you need to control the new tab, e.g. closing the tab or act on its content you are forced to create the new tab by javascript and keep a reference to the new tab.